# How to get page id by page title in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am not able to get page id by page title in these cases when the words as space in between

1. just think
2. How are you

but I am able to get id when it is single word title like "user"

My code goes here

```
function get_ID_by_page_name($page_name)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $page_name_id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = '".$page_name."'");
    return $page_name_id;
}



$thinkid = ks_get_option('ks_thinkid'); //getting page title from theme option
echo $thinkid; // works successfull till this 

$the_page_id = get_ID_by_page_name($thinkid);
echo $the_page_id;
```

Comment: do you have separate pages where you have to get id.?

Comment: Do you want to fetch page id by title or page slug because you are using post_name and not page_title but in your example as well as question you have shown page title?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

finally I found a solution for this, thankyou for the help for others who may searching like me for Page id from page title here is solution

```
function get_page_id_by_title($title)
{
$page = get_page_by_title($title);
return $page->ID;
}


get_page_id_by_title('how are you');
```

Comment: Why this worked and the simpler code by @WisdmLabs didn't I have no idea, but thank you!

Comment: It's now 2024, 10 years later, `get_page_by_title()` has been deprecated since WP 6.2.0.

Answer (score 3):

```
$page = get_page_by_title( 'How are you' ); //as an e.g.

echo $page->ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
global $wpdb;

$page_name = "Your page title";

$page_id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name
 = '".$page_name."' AND post_type = 'page'");

return $page_id;
```

Code taken from this link : http://chandreshrana.blogspot.in/2016/03/how-to-get-page-id-from-page-title.html

Answer (score 0):

try this to get page id from page title:

```
$page = get_page_by_title( 'Sample Page' );
```